# How can I use the member variable in class when using QThread?

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I'm testing the QThread with pyqt.

Below is the my test code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class TestThread(QThread):
    set_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.int_var = 0
        self.bool_var = False
        self.list_var = list()

    def run(self):
        pass

    def get_int_var(self):
        return self.int_var

    def get_bool_var(self):
        return self.bool_var

    def get_list_var(self):
        return self.list_var

    def stop(self):
        self.quit()
        self.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_thread = TestThread()

    print(test_thread.get_int_var())
    print(test_thread.get_bool_var())
    print(test_thread.get_list_var())
```

I'd like to use member variable in class.

But when I call the get function, error occurs and error message is follows.

ErrorMessage "AttributeError: 'TestThread' object has no attribute 'int_var'"

Comment: Typo: change `def __int__` to `def __init__`.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks

Comment: I solved it the way "musicamante" told me. Thank you.